# USB 3 Lightning Camera Adapter to Roland MIDI UM-One interface on iPhone with iOS 12

Tags: iphone, ios, usb, garageband

I am running iOS 12.1.2 on my iPhone X. I am trying to use GarageBand with a Microkorg synthesizer, and am connecting them using a Roland UM-One Mk2 MIDI interface and a USB 3 Lightning Camera Adapter.

This setup seems to work fine on my iPad - also running the most recent version of iOS 12.

But when I plug everything into my iPhone, I cannot play the GarageBand instrument with the synth.

Also, the expected lights on the MIDI interface are on in both cases.

Is there a setting on the iPhone that must be changed? I literally just had to plug in to the iPad to make it work - no extra effort there.